# Multithreading with loop

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, loops, custom-controls

I have made an application for reading RSS and outputting it to labels, but what I am using is a Timer since I want to loop it. 
I want as soon as my thread finishes, to wait 3 mins, then restart it.
What the thread/timer does it makes a panel with 2 labels, one for title and one for description, and in it, i put the rss item's value.

The timer does what I need, but the control becomes unresponsive.

btw. I am using a custom control.

Comment: What kind of app? Windows forms?

Comment: "btw. I am using a custom control" Class library

Comment: You can define a custom control in lots of different project types. In any case, look at using the BackgroundWorker class. That should let you perform the work without blocking the UI.

Comment: Yeah, but does it loop every 3 mins like i can with a Timer ?
I have basically no experience with backgroundworkers thats why.

Comment: You could either tell the timer to call the BGworker every 3 minutes or have the BGworker thread loop and sleep for 3 minutes at the end of each loop.

Comment: Since we are talking about the backgroundworker, when i was trying to access panel1 i got a illegal cross thread too

Comment: I also have not used the BGworker much. You may have to return the values using the ReportProgress method and actually interact with the controls from the UI thread, possibly from the ProgressChanged or RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming 4.0) First, make this Extension Method in a Module in your project.  This will handle cross thread UI operations.

```
<Extension()> _
Public Sub SomeCrossThreadAction(Of T As ISynchronizeInvoke)(ByRef objTarget As T, ByVal actCrossThreadAction As Action(Of T))

    If objTarget.InvokeRequired Then

        objTarget.Invoke(actCrossThreadAction, New Object() {objTarget})

    Else

        actCrossThreadAction(objTarget)

    End If

End Sub
```

Second, define the method that will be called by your thread which leverages the Extension Method to add controls to the form.  Here is an example (Me in this case being the Form.  You can add a form parameter (or some other type) to this method if you wish to pass one in to replace "Me"):

```
Private Sub ThreadsWork()

    Dim lblTest As New Label
    lblTest.Text = "Some Text."

    Me.SomeCrossThreadAction(Sub(frm As Form) frm.Controls.Add(lblTest))

End Sub
```

In your Timer Elapsed Event Handler:

```
    Dim t As New Threading.Thread(Sub(x) ThreadsWork())
    t.Start()
```

Obviously, this isn't *exactly* what you're looking for, but may be enough of a lead for you.  That extension method will work on more than just the Form Type.